# Is there a way to align desktop icons to (a vertical and horizontal) grid?

Tags: gnome, compiz, metacity, desktop-icons

Is there a way to align desktop icons to (a vertical AND horizontal) grid.
like in Windows for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on desktop, and check 'keep aligned'. This automatically snaps the icons to grid.

[image]

Comment: o. i see. Are there any settings that align icons automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote `iconic` to let you define a grid size to suit your needs. Additionally it will:

- Allow you to move icons to any of three monitors
- Not suffer the "lost icon syndrome" that occurs when monitors of multiple resolutions are used
- Sort icons alphabetically, alphabetically with "Link to" prefix ignored, sort by modified date ascending or date descending
- Allow different grid size (columns x rows) depending on monitor, EG more on 4K monitor than 2K monitor
- Instant **Test** button for quick experimentation on column x row changes or reserved space changes for monitor left, top, right or bottom areas
- **Test** button will last for x seconds defined by you, clear all windows before test and restore them after test
- Bash script for easy modifications

You can get the script on [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic).

Here's the main screen:

[image: iconic main menu.png]

Visit the [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic) page for **iconic** to see all the other screens, explanations and a copy of the script.