# Is there a way to automatically reorganize desktop icons?

Tags: unity, nautilus, icons

Gnome has *"Keep Aligned"*, Windows *"Rearrange Automatically"*; can't find it in Unity. Is it perhaps because we're not intended to have icons in the desktop?

Comment: Matthew, please say, where? Been looking for the switch or menu entry both in settings, dash and desktop to no avail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mathew, I found the menu you mention. It's roght click on the desktop but it requires a triggering a reorg. What I'm looking for, if it exists, is somethings that reorganizes the icons as any enters or leaves the desktop; like i.e. when you plug an USB drive in or out.

Comment: Although this question is about an EOL Ubuntu version the same concept applies to newer versions on Life Support. Instead of closing as `not reproducible` I'm VTC as duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/32058/is-there-a-way-to-align-desktop-icons-to-a-vertical-and-horizontal-grid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to align desktop icons to (a vertical and horizontal) grid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32058/is-there-a-way-to-align-desktop-icons-to-a-vertical-and-horizontal-grid)